# How can i put this values programatically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am getting some list of values from DataBase

```
var priceData = [];

data.jobs[i].low will give me the Value 

 for ( var i = 0; i < data.jobs.length; i++) 
{
// Need Help Here 

}
```

Now please tell me how can i construct the Array as

```
var priceData = [[0,100.34],[1,108.31],[2,109.40],[3,104.87],[4,106.00]
```

Means 0 index will give me 100.34 where data.jobs[0].low provides me 100.34 value , sorry fro my english .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an other array, which contains the index of the iteration and the data

```
[i, data.jobs[i].low]
```

So it would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.jobs.length; i++)  { 
    priceData.push([i, data.jobs[i].low]);
}
```

---

**Update:** *The below suggestions are not relevant, as the data is indeed needed as 2d data. However I will leave it in case it is of any interest.*

But this means you have to access the values with `priceData[x][1]`. More convenient (and natural) would be to put the values directly into the array (and not create an array of arrays):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.jobs.length; i++)  { 
    priceData.push(data.jobs[i].low);
}
```

which would give you can array like this:

```
[100.34, 108.31, 109.40, 104.87, 106.00]
```

which can be accessed with `priceData[x]`.

In most cases there is no reason to store the index, as it is given implicitly by the position of the element in the array.

Comment: I want data in this format var priceData = [[0,100.34],[1,108.31],[2,109.40]]

Comment: @user663724: Yes, this is what the first snippet is doing. But why do you need it like that?

Comment: I need to store the index also .

Comment: @user663724: I got that. I asked you *why* you need to do that. What are you going to do with this data? I just want to help you and prevent you from having to deal with unnecessary complex data structures.

Comment: Thank you Felix Kling , I am actually co nstructing a Chart where the X axis data will have dates . SO on tool tip on the chart , i need to show for the particular date value , the value is this (It requires Two dimensional arrays )

Comment: @user663724: Ok :) Then makes absolutely sense... sorry for me being so persistent ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( var i = 0; i < data.jobs.length; i++) 
{
    priceData[i] = data.jobs[i];

}
```

Comment: That is the same as `priceData = data.jobs` and not what the OP wants.